# AdMob: Do I need to request (download) a new interstitial every time an interstitial finishes showing?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, interstitial, ads

https://developers.google.com/admob/games

AdMob: Do I need to call RequestInterstitial() to download a new interstitial everytime after interstitial.Show() finishes showing an interstitial?
I honestly have no idea, do I call RequestInterstitial() to download data into interstitial once in the entire lifetime?
Or do I have to download an interstitial every time the previous one is shown?

I ask this question because I have a script that calls RequestInterstitial() once in the Start() function, and script that handles a button press that will call if(intestitial.IsLoaded(){interstitial.Show()} once.
Then I pressed the button once, and an interstitial appears. I close the interstitial, and press the button again. Nothing happens anymore.
I'm new to advertising, and I'm not sure how (often) to load the interstitials.

Google's documentation doesn't have any solutions specifically targeted at my problem. I couldn't find any answers through a Google search as well.

The example on Admob's docuemntation seems to me that I only need to load it once.
Anyone knows?

P.S. I am using Unity3D
Also, how does it work with AdBuddiz as well? Do I have to re-download the ads, or do I only need to Cache the ad/s once?

Answer (score 3):

when you load an ad in all ad network you request only one ad .

so after you click on your button and the ad is shown you will to request a new ad.

Best way to implement a Second Request from ad network is to implement an ad listener so when the user closed the first ad you will load a new ad by calling RequestInterstitial() method

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same answer in C++ and found this [well hidden comment in one of the AdMob examples](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/cocos2dx-cpp-sample/blob/23b418869e90f004fe41046e5816db5d17cc5da3/admob/Classes/FirebaseAdMobScene.cpp#L577-L580):

Note: InterstitialAd is a single-use object that can load and show a single AdMob interstitial ad.

which means not only do you have re-request the Ad, you cannot reuse the object you've created and have to dispose of the old object and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial

> A single InterstitialAd object can be used to request and display
> multiple interstitial ads over the course of an activity's lifespan,
> so you only need to construct it once.

So it seems to me that the InterstitialAd can be static and just reused, as can the AdRequest object be static and reused, and all that needs to be done is to call

```
static InterstitialAd _interstitial;
static AdRequest _request;
...
_interstitial.LoadAd(_request);
```

using the static defined objects each time you want to prep a new ad, either after the old one closes or upon Scene Load or what have you.